# How to include partials using ng-include(AngularJS) in IBM Websphere Portlet

Tags: portlet, angularjs-ng-include

I am using ng-include directive to include partial views in IBM websphere Portlet.The code snippet is below

1.Defining  render URL

```
 <portlet:defineObjects /> 
 <portlet:renderURL var="resourceURL" windowState="MINIMIZED" portletMode="view">
     <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/partials/list.html" />   
 </portlet:renderURL>
```

2.Main.js

```
 <script>
    var myApp = angular.module("App", []);
    myApp.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope ) 
          { 
                $scope.page='<%=resourceURL%>';
           });
</script>
```

3.Home.jsp

```
<div  id="<portlet:namespace />main" data-ng-app="App" data-ng-controller="myCtrl"  >   
   <div ng-include src="'page'"></div>
<div>
```

But the partials are not included. Can anyone suggest me how to fix this?Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change your code to go to the portlet context path:

Replace:

```
<%=resourceURL%>
```

with

```
<%=renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath():%>
```

This will work:

```
<div ng-include="'<%= renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath() + "/scripts/mypage.tpl.html") %>'"></div>
```